# Finding a key-value pair present only in the first dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'firstvalue':1, 'secondvalue':2, 'fourthvalue':4}
dict2 = {'firstvalue':1, 'thirdvalue':3, 'fourthvalue':5}
```

I get `set(['secondvalue'])` as a result upon doing:

```
dict1.viewkeys() - dict2
```

I need `{'secondvalue':2}` as a result.
 When I use set, and then do the `-` operation, it does not give the desired result as it consists of `{'fourthvalue:4}` as well.
How could I do  it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple variation with `set` difference:

```
res = {k: dict1[k] for k in dict1.keys() - dict2.keys()}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, sir. If I were to do this for a large dictionary would there be any in-efficiency involved? Large dictionary, in average case, consisting of 15-16 thousand key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC and providing a solution to `Finding a key-value pair present only in the first dictionary` as specified, you could take a set from the `key`/`value` pairs as tuples, subtract both sets and construct a dictionary from the result:

```
dict(set(dict1.items()) - set(dict2.items()))
# {'fourthvalue': 4, 'secondvalue': 2}
```

Comment: I'd say this is probably not what OP wants. Try it with `dict1 = {'firstvalue':2, 'secondvalue':2, 'fourthvalue':4}`

Comment: Hmm good point the values are subtracted when doing this @tobias_k ... went too fast

Comment: Who known, maybe this _is_ what OP wants. Might want to point this out in the answer, though.

Comment: Don't think so... @tobias_k `present only in the first dictionary`

Comment: Well, according to just the title, OP would want `fourthvalue:4` in the result, too... ("key-value pairs")

Comment: Ah cos he does say key-value pair not just key. Athough in this case if the value in the first dictionary is lower, even though it is different the key-value pair will not be present in the result @tobias_k

Comment: Modified my answer to what seems to be more coherent according to what OP is actually asking for, although quite possibly it is just wrongly phrased and it's just finding the difference in keys @tobias_k as you assumed. Thanks in any case for pointing out

Comment: Respected seniors, I too tried the above solution but got that `'fourthvalue':4` (undesired) along with the desired one `'secondvalue':2`.  The same I have mentioned in my 3rd and 2nd last line in the question. I am inclined to use sets as I have done it all over...I need to find the difference, intersection which I did with sets with success. But, when it came to uniqueness(only that key [and the value]  which is not there in dict2 ) set is not helping.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `-` is that (in this context) it is an operation of  `dict_keys` and thus the results will have no values. Using `-` with `viewitems()` does not work, either, as those are tuples, i.e. will compare both keys *and* values.

Instead, you can use a conditional dictionary comprehension, keeping only those keys that do not appear in the second dictionary. Other than `Counter`, this also works in the more general case, where the values are not integers, and with integer values, it just checks whether a key is present irrespective of the value that is accociated with it.

```
>>> dict1 = {'firstvalue':1, 'secondvalue':2, 'fourthvalue':4}
>>> dict2 = {'firstvalue':1, 'thirdvalue':3, 'fourthvalue':5}
>>> {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if k not in dict2}
{'secondvalue': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2.x:**

```
dict1 = {'firstvalue':1, 'secondvalue':2, 'fourthvalue':4}
dict2 = {'firstvalue':1, 'thirdvalue':3, 'fourthvalue':5}


keys = dict1.viewkeys() - dict2.viewkeys()
print ({key:dict1[key] for key in keys})
```

output:

```
{'secondvalue': 2}
```